# Google recaptcha verification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello when i Submit a Form Sometimes i got a Google captcha verification failed.

is there a way to not have this error or Skip Recaptcha or make it alway's True ?

Html :

```
<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response" value="03AOLTBLR2tBWnlAhqZlqeMmv3PY_T-cezG63SPaDcC_VcWMBkSt60VvSkHjogTxtAoRhRiPoEglg6whL8vIzUkXEYVKd3Blcyw1TQjMMQmYTbL9u0bwmcJ2utefrU3aMU8hx8Z9MMYOAWPwELIM7RRLybXVVr0T10UeYoBAg-xQffwyTqFo9t_JvcfSHeFkqfoAAodv35I4dBdTP-qtte9BQXR_WLT5F0y53dY0IHU1l3N8wjWYQUkr2ybQcH0gs0C_j4xi4lHbkGU8gJXc-XHBxkIeR56_IsCZ-nUzlTdzCLE968JoCUBI-IXA1DSavS_mBPBONUmfrxFn5guR5gQA2Zfbw0RQLCWe1mRM5j8J7WcL77VHwH6tBWUUPjCXDLAwRFsIhB66OWGG1x2nWE8p5xtt21Gsw93wcsDL3e5qNWQurOd9oHS6_UTeE3_FcFID7Ijld6kXIVCNA97o0oKVOwiGNOiwPdv6wvQZZnAiYb-QX2B2TzuWbvYHf22gBj2t_HK2ozhsXy4ujmoY0XOSlmCsbemu5Y0A">
```

this is the Form Id html :

```
<form name="agxthird" id="agxthird" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

is there a way to Aviod this on Jquery or Js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the developer, you can add in a flag to - for example - load the recaptcha unless there is a testing parameter in the URL or something like that. Although this is not advised if this code is in production.

Also, try a different browser and ensure you aren't using any automation/controlling software like Puppeteer.

Otherwise there's not much you can do.